# /cgi-bin/printenv - doesn't execute - outputs the script itself

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, cgi-bin

I am trying to get cgi scripts working with a clean build of httpd-2.4.6 on SciLinux 6 - x86_64.

My httpd.conf file: http://pastebin.com/P0CKYfqU

This is essentially the one that was installed - with a few edits.

I do have:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/tmp/apps/cgi-bin/"
```

in the httpd.conf file.

I built httpd using the following configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/var/tmp/apps --with-apr=/var/tmp/apps/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/var/tmp/apps/bin/apu-1-config --with-pcre=/var/tmp/apps/bin/pcre-config --enable-cgi
```

I have done the following to /var/tmp/apps/cgi-bin/printenv

1. edited the #! line
2. done chmod a+rx

The command works from the command line.

However, when I go to localhost:8001/cgi-bin/printenv I just see the script itself - not the output of the script.

I'm sure I must be missing a `configure` option or an `httpd.conf` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turrns out that in httpd-2.4.6 the mod_cgi module is not built or enabled by default.

Here is a build recipe which works:

Build httpd with there configure options:

```
configure \
  --prefix=$TOP \
  --with-apr=$TOP/bin/apr-1-config \
  --with-apr-util=$TOP/bin/apu-1-config \
  --with-pcre=$TOP/bin/pcre-config \
  --enable-modules=all \
  --enable-proxy \
  --enable-proxy-http \
  --disable-userdir \
  --enable-cgi
```

And then in the httpd.conf file make sure the mod_cgi.so module is loaded:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

To get the `printenv` cgi script to work, add the `ExecCGI` option to the options for the /cgi-bin/ directory:

```
 <Directory "/var/tmp/apps/cgi-bin">
     AllowOverride None
-    Options None
+    Options +ExecCGI
     Require all granted
 </Directory>
```